# CSS: keep height of banner while increasing text size

Tags: html, css

I need to increase the font-size of my title, however doing so also alters the height of ma home banner. And this generates a gap for the image that is on the right that shouldn't be there, because the image should have contact with the bottom limit of the home banner.

**Correct but small text**:

[image]

**Incorrect but big text**:

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-fluid my_header_bg_color">

    <header class="my_header_bg_color">
        <br>
        <br>


        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-6">

                <div class="my_custom_banner_left">

                    <p class="my_title_banner">Stickers personalizados</p>


                    <p>Fáciles de ordenar por internet, diseño de conceptos gratis, envíos rápidos </p>

                </div>

                <div class="row my_bottom_margin">


                    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-5">

                        <a href="stickers" class="btn btn-azul text-white btn-block">Comprar</a>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-5">

                        <a href="{% url 'shop:SamplePackPage' %}" class="btn btn-naranja text-white btn-block">Muestras
                        </a>


                    </div>



                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 ml-auto">

                <img class="my_image_banner my_image_padding" src="{% static 'img/banner-home2.png' %}">

            </div>

        </div>




    </header>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.my_title_banner {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.my_header_bg_color {
    background-color: #00A388;
}

.my_custom_banner_left {
    margin-left: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: I dont understand exactly your problem. Can you explain that more exactly or more in detail?

Comment: I need to increase my paragrpah text size, but when I do that in CSS the banner height also increases. This affects the image in the right, now we have a gap between the image and the bottom of the banner (image 2).

Answer (score 1):

Simply define a height for the banner:

```
.my_title_banner {
    height:400px;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

or, if you'd like the banner to have a variable height, you can make sure the image stays flush with the bottom off the banner like so:

```
.your-banner {
    position:relative
}

.image-inside-banner {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0
}
```